# Refactoring function arguments with elpy

Tags: python, emacs, refactoring, elpy

I am getting more and more used to working with elpy and damn it is amazing! However I can't seem to utilize the `elpy-refactor-rename' to also include correction in function input e.g.

```
def mydef(a,b,c):
  return a+b

res = mydef(1,2,3)
```

I want to refactor `mydef` to

```
def mydef(a,b):
  return a+b

res = mydef(1,2)
```

The project I am working have a lot of unused arguments and something like this would tremendously help me refactor it all.

Comment: You can use vertico or ivy to do project-wide search & replace

Comment: But the functionality is not present in elpy itself?

Comment: Yes. I suspect elpy have this feature.

Comment: And that is the question - if it is, where and how because regular refactor-rename does not take into account the method arguments

Comment: Sorry, what I want to say is I suspect elpy doesn't have this feature. Asking on the GitHub should be a faster way.